# Does magic resistance reduction of Abyssal Scepter stack with Malady?

Tags: league-of-legends

Do they stack? The tooltip says one of them is Unique Passive the other one is Unique aura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do stack with each other.

The Unique Passive/Unique Aura part means that they don't stack with other copies of the same item - that is, if your team has two Abyssal Scepters, the enemies' magic resistance isn't reduced by 40, but only 20.

The general rule is that Unique Passives from different items do stack, unless the two passives have the same name (such as "Eyes of Pain" on Liandry's Torment and Haunting Guise).  If the passive is unnamed than you can assume it will stack with other unnamed passives from a different item.

Comment: And Liandri's Torment does not stack with Haunting Guise right?

Comment: No they don't stack. If the unique passive/aura has the same name then that means they don't stack with each other.

Comment: So it's a yes, not a no.

Comment: Correct, they don't stack.  You can't have two "Eyes of Pain" passives.